# Multiple level host alias in ssh config

Tags: linux, ssh, shell

My system admin manages a set of SSH configs for our remote servers, these configs are updated and pushed to my `/etc/ssh/` folder regularly. However, host names in the managed ssh configs are too long to type (I'm lazy). Can I create host name aliases in my `~/.ssh/config`? Note that this is not alias for `HostName`.

For example, my admin pushes configs to my `/etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/` which look like this:

```
Host a.long.host.name
    HostName real-host-name.example.com
    ProxyCommand some proxy command
    ...
```

I want to give `a.long.host.name` a different, shorter name so I can type `ssh foo` instead of `ssh a.long.host.name`, I don't want to use shell alias because other commands like `scp` will need separate shell aliases.

I think `ProxyCommand ssh -J localhost a.long.host.name` would work, but localhost must be have `sshd` enabled, which I can't do.

Comment: I found an answer here which addressed this for me:  
https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/61666/503115  
I hope that helps other travelers who might find themselves along this path.  ‍♂️

Comment: @jg3 Hmm.. Can you elaborate? That answer is helpful if the long host name and the short one are both in the same config file, in my case, the long host name is in a system config file, I need to add a short name in my own `.ssh/config`.

Answer (score 0):

"Host a.long.host.name" is an arbitrary name, it can be anything you like so long as it's not a duplicate or a reserved word etc. It is effectively an ssh config specific alias. User specific ssh configs will take precedence over system level configs in /etc/ssh/

Comment: The problem is I don't want to duplicated the managed configs in my personal ssh config file.

Comment: I don't think there is a built in method to reference them, but only partially. One method is to create multiple ssh configs to separate work from personal. Something like:
 `ssh -F ~/.ssh/workconf ` which could be an edited instance of /etc/ssh/config in which you could amend the server name aliases to be shorter to type.  There is also an `Include` facility where you can reference external ssh config in your main one (ie Include workconf). This would mean you could ssh foo which comes from your work severs list without having to specify a file on the command line.